# Matplotlib: Argument dimensions are incompatible fill between curves

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, fill

I have this plot.

```
fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(7.5,7.5))

ax.plot(time, y)
ax.plot(time, y1, color='red')
ax.plot(time, y2, color='black')
```

[image]

I want to fill the area between the black and red curves. So I am doing:

```
y1=np.array(y1)
y2=np.array(y2)
ax.fill_between(time, y1, y2,where=y1>=y2,color='grey', alpha='0.5')
```

But it returns the following:

```
ValueError: Argument dimensions are incompatible
```

Comment: Can you include the shape of time, y1, and y2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, you do not need to put a `where` condition for what you want to do. [fill_between](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.fill_between) function only requires to put the maximum array and minimum array for your proposal of equal length of OX array (`time` in your case).

The following is an example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(7.5,7.5))

time = np.linspace(0,1,100)
y = np.sin(time*10)
y1 = y - 0.5
y2 = y + 0.5

ax.plot(time, y)
ax.plot(time, y1, color='red')
ax.plot(time, y2, color='black')

ax.fill_between(time, y1, y2, color='grey', alpha='0.5')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

That gives the following output:
[image]

To see how `where` works, change the line to this one in my example:

```
ax.fill_between(time, y1, y2, where=(time<0.5), color='grey', alpha='0.5')
```

Or this as another conditional example:

```
ax.fill_between(time, y1, y2, where=(y1<0.0), color='grey', alpha='0.5')
```

As you can see, what it makes is to create a boolean array and draws only on that points of OX axis where the condition is `true`.
You can make your boolean array by hand also (length of OX axis, of course).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the arguments `color` and `alpha` need to be passed as `color =...,alpha=...`.

Correct:
`ax.fill_between(x, y_min, y_max,color = color, alpha=0.1)`

Wrong:
`ax.fill_between(x, y_min, y_max,color, alpha=0.1)`